# What is the number of triangles with integer sides, given the length of the longest side?

Tags: combinatorics, triangles

Suppose $a,b,c \in\mathbb N$, and the value of $c$ is known and fixed, while $a$ and $b$ are unknown and are both smaller than $c$. What is the total number of unique triangles possible with $a, b$ and $c$ as its sides?

Comment: Do you mean the natural numbers? Does "known" mean "fixed" and "unknown" mean "variable" (in which case you should not mention $a,b$ in the final question)? And can there be more than one triangle with given sides $a,b,c$? (Under the usual definition there can, for instance realted by translation or rotation, but the 'combinatorics' tag suggests you do not mean that.) In short, please reformulate the question more carefully so people can figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Unless there are some other conditions, there are an infinite number of possible triangles (assuming $n>1$): just take the sides to be n, n+k and n+k+1 for any positive integer k.

Comment: @Old John : Apologies.

Comment: No problems! - The question looks more interesting now.

Comment: Should degenerate triangles be counted as well?

Comment: @ celtschk : No, you need not count them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the total number of unique triangles possible with $a$, $b$ and $c$ as its sides?

The formula you need is $$\left\lfloor\frac{(c-1)^2}{4}\right\rfloor$$

As noted [here](http://oeis.org/A002620), it counts "the number of noncongruent integer-sided triangles with largest side $c$". See [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589119) as well.

Comment: Won't this overcount because it allows $a,b$ to equal $c$, while the poster asks for $a,b$ smaller than $c$?  Not that it would be hard to exclude those cases...

Comment: No, it does not. $c=1$ and $c=2$ are $0$ for obvious reasons. For $c=3$, you only have $1$ triangle ($(2,2,3)$), which matches with the formula's result. For $c=4$, you have $(2,3,4)$ and $(3,3,4)$, which gives $2$ triangles... you can go on and check. The article I linked to gives a derivation for an alternative formula.

Comment: Anyway, I suppose I should have said my point: OP should have tried out a few cases and then checked out the OEIS.

Comment: Your formula is correct, as is the OEIS comment about "triangles with largest side $c$".  The extra triangles, allowing $b=c$, number $c$, corresponding to $a = 1,\ldots,c$.  But this is precisely the difference between your $\lfloor \frac{(c-1)^2}{4} \rfloor$ and the quantity $\lfloor \frac{(c+1)^2}{4} \rfloor$ commented on in the OEIS.

Answer (score 5):

For a non-degenerate triangle, we need
$$
c\lt a+b\quad\text{and}\quad1\le a,b\le c
$$

---

**Generating Function Approach**

The generating function for the number of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a+b=k$ and $1\le a,b\le c$ is
$$
\left(x+x^2+\cdots+x^c\right)^2=\left(x\frac{x^c-1}{x-1}\right)^2
$$
Now,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k\gt c}\left[x^k\right]\left(x\frac{x^c-1}{x-1}\right)^2
&=\sum_{k\gt c}\left[x^k\right]\left(\color{#C00}{x^2}\color{#090}{-2x^{c+2}}\color{#00F}{+x^{2c+2}}\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)x^j\\
&=\sum_{k\gt c}\left[\color{#C00}{(k-1)_+}\color{#090}{-2(k-c-1)_+}\color{#00F}{+(k-2c-1)_+}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k\ge0}\left[(k+c)_+-2k_++(k-c)_+\right]\\
&=\sum_{k\ge0}\left[(c-k)+(k-c)_+\right]\\
&=\frac{c(c+1)}2
\end{align}
$$
Since we want $a\le b$, we need to add the number of ways $a=b$, which is the number of even numbers in $[c+1,2c]$, that is $\left\lfloor\frac{c+1}2\right\rfloor$, and divide by $2$:
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac12\left(\frac{c(c+1)}2+\left\lfloor\frac{c+1}2\right\rfloor\right)}
$$

---

**Brute Force Counting Approach**

The possible choices for $a+b=k\ge c+1$ and $1\le a,b\le c$, are
$$
(j,k-j)
$$
where $k-c\le j\le c$. There are $2c-k+1$ cases for each $k$. This gives the total number of cases to be
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=c+1}^{2c}(2c-k+1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^c(c-k+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^ck\\[3pt]
&=\frac{c(c+1)}2
\end{align}
$$
Since we want $a\le b$, we need to add the number of ways $a=b$, which is the number of even numbers in $[c+1,2c]$, that is $\left\lfloor\frac{c+1}2\right\rfloor$, and divide by $2$:
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac12\left(\frac{c(c+1)}2+\left\lfloor\frac{c+1}2\right\rfloor\right)}
$$

---

**Alternate Forms of the Answer**

**Form 2:**

Since $c-2\left\lfloor\frac c2\right\rfloor=\frac{1-(-1)^c}2$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\left(\frac{c(c+1)}2+\left\lfloor\frac{c+1}2\right\rfloor\right)
&=\frac12\left(\frac{c(c+1)}2+\frac{2c+1+(-1)^{c+1}}4\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{2c(c+2)+1-(-1)^c}8}
\end{align}
$$
**Form 3:**

Since $\frac{c(c+1)}2$ is an integer, it can pass inside the floor. Since a square is either $0$ or $1$ mod $4$, $\left\lfloor\frac{(c+1)^2}2\right\rfloor$ is even. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\left(\frac{c(c+1)}2+\left\lfloor\frac{c+1}2\right\rfloor\right)
&=\frac12\left\lfloor\frac{(c+1)^2}2\right\rfloor\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left\lfloor\frac{(c+1)^2}4\right\rfloor}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: U mean in half of the cases a will lead b and in other half b will lead a..excluding the cases where a=b..

Comment: @Akulsharma: Yes. So the number of cases where $a\le b$, is $\frac12$ the number of total cases plus the number of cases where $a=b$.

Comment: in fuction generating approach why u considered x^(2c+2)? Coz the maximum sum of a+b possible is 2c

Comment: @Akulsharma: because $x^{2c+2}$ is part of the generating function. It comes from $x^2\left(1-x^c\right)^2=x^2-2x^{c+2}+x^{2c+2}$. That then needs to be multiplied by $\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)x^j$.

Comment: I did it in a different first I find the number of triangles possible (considering a<=b) for c+1 and so on till 2c..but I ignored the term x^(2c+2) because it can not yield ( c+1,2c)..

Comment: @Akulsharma: Well, that should work, because the blue terms end up in the final $(k-c)_+$ which is $0$ when $k\le c$, and cancels the $(c-k)$ when $k\gt c$. So you shouldn't need to worry about that term if you limit the range of the sum.

Comment: I got the answer thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you consider $(a,b,c)=(3,4,5)$ to give a different triangle from $(a,b,c)=(4,3,5)$, you seem to be either asking for the number of elements in
$$
  \{\,(a,b)\in\mathbb N^2\mid 0<a< n \text{ and } 0<b, n \text{ and } a+b>n\,\}
$$
  or  for the number of elements in
$$
  \{\,(a,b)\in\mathbb N^2\mid 0<a\leq b< n \text{ and } a+b>n\,\}.
$$
Surely you can find the answers to these easy questions? Make a drawing of dots inside a square if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the triangle inequality. If $a\leq b\leq c$, it is only required that $a+b>c$, so we need to count the number of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a\leq b\leq c$ and $c<a+b$. Can you go from here?

Comment: I tried but wasn't able to solve the question properly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/908859)

Comment: @GuyFsone I'm happy to add more to the answer (as I have), but it was decided in [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/do-hints-belong-in-answers-or-comments) that hints should be posted as answers. Given that the asker stated that he/she did not know where to start, I thought such a hint would be appropriate and could be helpful.

Comment: @Akulsharma I'll add a little more to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Triangle inequality reduces to $c<a+b$ (the other two are obvious), so you need to count the pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\le b\le c$ satisfying $c<a+b\le 2c$. These are:
$$(1,c), (2,c-1), (2,c) \ldots (c,c)$$

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little program who gave me the results in the table, but I can't find a closed formula to get numbers of triangles $n$ directly from $c$

Hope this can be useful

**Edit**

I found it! Thanks to *Mathematica*, which means *I don't know exactly how to explain*

$$n=\frac{1}{8} \left[2 c (c+2)+(-1)^{c+1}+1\right]$$
$$...$$

$
\begin{array}{r|r}
 c & n\\
\hline
 5 & 9 \\
 10 & 30 \\
 15 & 64 \\
 20 & 110 \\
 25 & 169 \\
 30 & 240 \\
 35 & 324 \\
 40 & 420 \\
 45 & 529 \\
 50 & 650 \\
 55 & 784 \\
 60 & 930 \\
 65 & 1089 \\
 70 & 1260 \\
 75 & 1444 \\
 80 & 1640 \\
 85 & 1849 \\
 90 & 2070 \\
 95 & 2304 \\
 100 & 2550 \\
\end{array}
$